# Fnding last item

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I need to extract the longest single-spaced substring from the end of a multi-spaced string.

For example from the string:

```
    "1234  sw   twilight street      Winter City Park"
```

I would want to match "Winter City Park", since it is the rightmost single-spaced segment. I don't mind if I catch " Winter City Park" but if there is a way to omit that leading space it would be more elegant

I thought negative lookahead would have been the answer but I am not getting the result I want, with the regex pattern: `[a-z ]+(?!\s{2,})`.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*\b(?!.*  )
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*` Optionally match a single space followed by 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!.*  )` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 consecutive spaces to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3jWlK/1)

**Note** that `\s` can also match newlines

Comment: Should it not find `multiple spaces` , when looking at `1234  sw   twilight street      multiple spaces  test a b c`  ?  (Because of " the **longest** single-spaced substring" )

Comment: @Luuk I think the OP want to find `the rightmost single-spaced segment` so in that case it should not find `multiple spaces`

Comment: @Luuk Maybe you have a good point if it should be the longest one, but I assumed that the OP want to have the longest possible match with single words separated by a single space

Comment: anyway this is a nice solution to find the last single-spaced-substring 

Comment: @the fourth bird can you help me better understand the use of ?:. So many times I have wanted to match sentences that are single-spaced, but it never dawned on me to place the space outside the brackets, so instead of ( [a-z]), I did ([a-z ]), knowing that I did not want double spaces but not knowing what to do about it. Now with your example, I see clearly what ' [a-zA-Z]+ does but I am not clear on what the behavior of ?: befor it

Comment: @Luuk I dont want to match any multi-spaced segment at all and I want the end sub-string. In my example, Winter City Park is at the end, and has no multi-space in it. If I were to add street to it, then that would break the requirement for no multi-space

Comment: @JonWayn the `(?:...)` syntax is a non capture group so we can repeat the whole grouped part.